# show dialog with custom effect, like: from (hidden) left to final left position

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

Example: this is the function i use to show a dialog

```
function pop_up_extra(div, titulo,h,w){
                        $( "#" + div ).dialog({
                            autoOpen: false,
                            show: "explode",
                            modal: true,
                            height: 'auto',
                            width: w,
                            title: titulo

                        });
            $( "#" + div ).dialog( "open" );
            $(".ui-widget-overlay").click (function () {      $("#pop").dialog( "close" );  });
            return false;

}
```

something like:  http://jsfiddle.net/YcZFj/2/

how should I update the `show` method??

PS: please edit the title if you consider (i am spanish thinker)

Comment: Don't know really what you are trying to achieve. What is it, that you want to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: i want to change the show effect to something similar to the jsfiddle effect i posted, is it posible? (custom show effect)

Comment: Could you provide for a jsfiddle with your actual code? You can choose to use jQuery UI there, too.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6nUt3/   ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `slide` effect of `show` options? Try this - http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/

Comment: haha, that was easy, but what if I want it to come from the right side?

Comment: I downloaded only `slide` effect from jquery site - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4624120/jquery.effects.slide.js
If you want change side, change 'Default Direction' on line 24 :) And i think its good template for your custom effects

Comment: nice! but isn't it posible to send 'right' as parameter? i see is an option but i dont know how to specify it; for exapmle: 'slide(right)'

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet The `right` in there is just the css property that should be saved

Comment: But i mean, instead of extending the effect methods, isn't it posible to make use of slide but pass 'right' as an option?